# Sqlite3 on iphone simulator

Tags: iphone, sqlite, simulator

I am struggling with this issue for couple days now. Hope I get some help here.

1. I imported an existing sqlite database to my Xcode 4.3 project. Run simulator. In the simulator I create a record from UI.
2. In the log I see that application copied the database in an internal directory/application.app/ directory.
3. From terminal I run sqlite3 and open the database from that internal directory and run select sql. I see that record. Great so far.
4. I close the app simulator and run it again. NOW THAT RECORD IS GONE !!!. How can I retain the data I create in simulator?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Does the copying occur only on the first run?

Comment: Copying happens only the first time.